# Are the atomic orbital balloons representations of some mathematical surface equation?

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

The atomic orbitals are usually shown in shape of fuzzy clouds and sometimes straight-up rigid/hollow balloon shapes.

I understand that actually they are representing the probability of finding electrons.
I have two questions.

Are the balloon shape representations good/accurate representations of showing regions with high probability of finding  electrons?

My main question is, are these shapes directly obtained from some mathematical equation for some surface? Like equations for ellipsoid, paraboloids etc.[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are. They are mappings of the so-called *spherical harmonics* and they pop up in a variety of physics contexts.